# angular2 user status on each page

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, status

How do you track if visitor status on every page with angular2. I already have a jwt based authentication which is working fine but now I want to be able to check on each route if visitor is logged in or not.

my service provider looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Configuration } from '../app.constants';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;
    public loggedIn: boolean;
    private actionUrl;

    constructor(private http: Http, private _configuration: Configuration) {
        // set token if saved in local storage
        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;

        if(this.token)
            this.loggedIn = true;

        this.actionUrl = _configuration.ServerWithApiUrl;
    }

    login(username, password): Observable<boolean> {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var data = ("_username=" + username + "&_password="+ password );

        return this.http.post(
            this.actionUrl + 'login_check',
            //JSON.stringify({ _username: username, _password: password }),
            data,
            { headers: headers }
        )
            .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response

                let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                if (token) {
                    // set token property
                    this.token = token;

                    // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ _username: username, token: token }));

                    // return true to indicate successful login
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    logout(): void {
        // clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
        this.token = null;
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn;
    }
}
```

and the my router

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { Login } from './login/';
import { Signup } from './signup/';
import { FrontendComponent } from './frontend/';
import { Blog } from './blog/';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/';
import { Results } from './filter/';
import { AuthGuard } from './common/auth.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: Login },
    { path: 'register', component: Signup },
    { path: 'blog', component: Blog },
    { path: '', component: FrontendComponent},
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out AuthGuard on routes.  Basically you create an authGuard like this:

```
// auth-guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private ls: LoginService, 
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.ls.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then add it to your routing like this:

```
{ path: 'themes',  loadChildren: './app/themes/themes.module#ThemesModule', canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ] },
{ path: 'settings',  loadChildren: './app/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule', canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ] },
```

If you have routes in feature modules, it will need to be added there also to the routes you wish to protect.